# Remove constants with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do simple derivatives in Javascript, for instance the derivative of

```
f(x) = 1-3x<sup>2</sup>-3+8x<sup>3</sup>+2
```

In Javascript I save it as `1-3*Math.pow(x,2)-3+8*Math.pow(x,3)+2`

So I start subtracting the exponents and this my code:

```
var math = op.replace(/x<sup>/g , '*Math.pow(x,');
math = math.replace(/<\/sup>/g , ')');
math = math.replace(/\,[0-9]/g, function (match, capture) {return parseInt(match.replace(',',''))-1;});
math = math.replace(/x/g, 'x,');
```

I am stucked because I don't know how to remove the constants. I have tried many things, but they don't work. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Regex'es may not be strong enough for your problem, because they don't take context under account - constant may be removed only if it's a free term but not when it is used as function parameter. Some regex engines support regex similar to simplified grammar productions, bug JS don't.

Comment: I'm scared - are you running `eval` on the string once you build it?

Comment: Also consider expressions like `((((1))))`, generally "pure" regex cant even match balanced parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick `replace(/(?:^|[-+])\d+([^x]|$)/g, '$1')`

The breakdown is:

`(?:^|[-+])` - non-capturing group that matches either the beginning of the string or a single plus or minus sign

`\d+` - one or more digits

`([^x]|$)` - capture group that matches either a non-x character or the end of the string

`$1` - takes the captured character, if it was there, and places it back into the expression

```js
var op = "1-3x<sup>2</sup>-3+8x<sup>3</sup>+2";

var math = op.replace(/(?:^|[-+])\d+([^x]|$)/g, '$1')
math = math.replace(/x<sup>/g, '*Math.pow(x,');
math = math.replace(/<\/sup>/g, ')');
alert(math)
```